# Popup text box starts glitching when i hover over it with hover color changing effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple Page with 3 Div elements, and I want when you hover over them for a box with specific text to show up.
First issue is, when it starts to change color the box dissapears and shows again.
Second issue is, when you have multiple divs, it works for only the first one.

```js
var trigger = document.getElementById("trigger");

var popup = document.getElementById("popup");

var text = document.getElementById("popup-text");

text.innerHTML = "This is the pop-up text.";

trigger.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
  popup.style.display = "block";

  popup.style.left = event.clientX + "px";
  popup.style.top = event.clientY + "px";
});

trigger.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
  popup.style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
#popup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
}

#trigger {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#trigger:hover {
  background-color: green;
  transition: 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<div id="trigger"></div>
<div id="trigger" style="background-color: aqua;"></div>
<div id="trigger" style="background-color: brown;"></div>
<div id="popup"><p id="popup-text"></p></div>
```

Comment: The first issue that jumps out (and will be the cause of the "it only works on the first element" problem) is that IDs must be unique. Adding `id="trigger"` to all your elements is invalid HTML.

Comment: The flickering will be because the element you show when mousing over, hides the element you were hovering and triggers the mouse out, and that gets into a loop, showing/hiding on repeat.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see is that you are generating a blue box in your css,

```
#trigger {
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
background-color: blue;
}
```

and you are applying the popup text to only occur on the blue box.

**To get the popup to apply to both aqua and brown boxes, end your "trigger" div *after* the "popup" div.**

I'm not sure what you wanted to be blue though>

You are going to come across more issues due to naming conventions with multiple divs with the same IDs (those should be unique to individual divs, class names can be used multiple times), but this answer is to only solve your popup issue.

I suggest looking a little more into trying to accomplish this with CSS only, and then moving onto how to do it with JS.

Good luck!